# Does there exist a generating function for the rational numbers?

Tags: generating-functions, rational-numbers

Since the rationals are countable, you can list them in a sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq 0}$ such that each rational appears at least once in the sequence. Is there such a listing $(a_n)_{n \geq 0}$ for which 
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} a_kx^k =a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + ...$$
has a closed form?

Comment: As a word of caution: if the answer turns out to be "no", a proof probably wouldn't be a good fit on this site.

Comment: What do you mean by "nice"?

Comment: I don't have anything specific in mind; I guess that closed form is enough, so I'll delete the "nice".

Comment: I made a similar question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4810270/f-cx-sum-k-0-infty-a-k-xk-a-0-a-1x-a-2x2-has-no-close

Answer (score 1):

Just some comments

How about using Cantor's pairing function ?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function

Although this does not reduce the fractions, so you get them multiple times.

$$\frac{5}{10} = \frac{1}{2}$$

for instance both occur.

Or maybe more interesting is this Calkin-Wilf tree :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calkin%E2%80%93Wilf_tree

Where all rationals occur only once !

Ofcourse this does not answer your question, it only lists the rationals.

Do you consider a lambert series as a closed form ??

I do not think there are closed forms in terms of simple functions.

The reason intuitively (my intuition) is this :

the n'th derivative of a 'simple' taylor series is often full of recursive properties.

But I do not see that happening for a sequence of all the rationals or even the rationals in a unit interval.

In fact I think even a taylor series containing the natural numbers only is usually not given by a closed form.

$$ \sum n x^{cn+d} $$
for fixed integer $c,d$

and results from series multisection can give rational functions but otherwise I do not see closed forms.

I will ask a question about that.
Thanks for the inspiration.

Comment: to the voters and readers , I edited

Comment: see also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4810270/f-cx-sum-k-0-infty-a-k-xk-a-0-a-1x-a-2x2-has-no-close

Answer (score 0):

The following are just some preliminary thougts on how we could start and approach the problem,
which are anyway too long for a comment.

Along the track of the [Farey sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence), we could build a 2 variables generating function
for all the rationals in $[0,1]$ as
$$
f(x,y) = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,n} {\sum\limits_{1 \le m \le n} {\left[ {\gcd (n,m) = 1} \right]{m \over n}x^{\,n} y^{\,m} } } 
$$
where $[P]$ denotes the [*Iverson bracket*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

We can also construct the o.g.f. above following instead the steps of the Stern-Brocot tree 
$$
\eqalign{
  & f_0 (x,y) = 0x + xy  \cr 
  & f_1 (x,y) = 0x + {1 \over 2}x^{\,2} y + xy  \cr 
  & f_2 (x,y) = 0x + {1 \over 3}x^{\,3} y + {1 \over 2}x^{\,2} y + {2 \over 3}x^{\,3} y^{\,2}  + xy  \cr 
  & \quad  \vdots  \cr} 
$$

We know the algorithm for constructing the single terms of the function, but (to my knowledge) not a closed expression for it,
even changing to exponential g.f. or others.

Comment: Dear G Cab: Your answer is quite related to my question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3972644/multivariate-generating-function-for-coprimes?noredirect=1&lq=1 I would like to hear your idea on this question as well, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using continued fractions to define an infinite-variable generating function (for rationals in the open unit interval)
$$
G(x_1, x_2, \dots):=\sum_{1\leq k} \sum_{1\leq n_1, n_2,\dots,n_k} 
[0,n_1,n_2,\dots ,n_k]x_1^{n_1} x_2^{n_2}\dots x_k^{n_k}
$$
(WARNING: I will be sloppy about indices, double representation of rationals by continued fractions, etc)

The first term in the above sum is $\log(1-x_1)$, and the second term is
$$
\sum_{1\leq n_1, n_2} \frac{n_2}{n_1n_2+1}x_1^{n_1}x_2^{n_2}
$$
which appears interesting enough and probably deserves a name. An idea to find a 'closed expression' is to express the coefficients as
$$
\cfrac{1}{n_1+\cfrac{1}{n_2}}=\frac{1}{n_1}\sum\frac{(-1)^k}{(n_1n_2)^k}
$$
which yields a sum involving lots of logarithms.

Another idea is to filter $G$ by sums of level $\ell$:
$$
G(x_1, x_2, \dots)=
\sum_{\ell=1}^\infty P(n_1, n_2, \dots ,n_\ell),
$$
where
$$
P(n_1, n_2, \dots n_\ell)=
\sum_{1\leq k, n_1+n_2+\dots+n_k=\ell}
[0,n_1, n_2, \dots n_k]x_1^{n_1}x_2^{n_k}\dots x_k^{n_k}.
$$

If $x=x_1=x_2=\dots$ we get
$$
G(x,x,\dots)=\sum_{1\leq \ell} 2^\ell x^\ell=\frac {1}{1-2x},
$$
since the sum of the $\ell$th level of the Farey tree is $2^\ell$.

It seems hopeless to find a closed form for $G$. On the other hand, note
$$
\sum_{1\leq k} \sum_{1\leq n_1, n_2,\dots,n_k} 
x_1^{n_1} x_2^{n_2}\dots x_k^{n_k}
=\frac{1}{1-x_1}
\left(1+\frac{1}{1-x_2}\left(1+\frac{1}{1-x_3}\dots\right)\right) 
$$
$$
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1-x_k}
$$